# omniauth w/ Twitter not working on rails 3.1.0.rc5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I have a Rails app running on 3.1.0.rc5, and I've setup omniauth for twitter exactly the same as seen here (https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter) but it's still not working.

The problem is that after Twitter is redirecting back to my callback URL I have request.env["omniauth.auth"] is nil, rack.auth is nil too.  I even went so far as to print out the entire request.env hash and didn't see anything like access_token or access_secret.

The only thing that doesn't look like my request token and secret is stored in action_dispatch.secret_token.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I got this working now.  My Gemfile was:

```
gem "oa-oauth", :require => "omniauth/oauth"
gem "twitter"
```

I changed it to:

```
gem 'omniauth', :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'json_pure' 
gem 'json'
```

And everything started working.  The request.env["omniauth.auth"] key was present etc.  I had to add the json gem lines because of a uninitialized constant JSON::ParserError error I was getting.  I think that is a bug in the release candidate.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I haven't been able to solve it with by adding the gems you've mentioned.  I tried with rc5 and now with rc6.  Any chance that there are others gems missing in your gem file that might be causing a nil for request.env["omniauth.auth"] ?